# Combining COUNT IF AND VLOOK UP EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have multiple spreadsheets in a `workbook` and I would like the following in basic `English` talk:

IF `worksheet1(cell)A3`, appears in 'worksheet2' column B - count how many times it appears in column b 'worksheet 2'

So in other words - Lets say `A3` = BOB smith - in work sheet 1
and appears 4 times in worksheet 2 - I want the formula to count the fact that `A3` 'Bob smith' is in worksheet 2 4 times, and come back and tell me 4.

I have attempted to do separate calculations - with use of Vlookups - then in another cell to count/do if statement
for example

```
=COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(A9,'To retire'!J:J,9,1))
=IF(J228=O233, 'worksheet2'!F440,0)
=VLOOKUP(A3,'worksheet2'!A:A,1,1)
```

Help would be very much appreciated, I am very stuck - I am unsure if I am looking into this too deeply or not enough! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is trivial when you use [`SUMPRODUCT`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumproduct-HP005209293.aspx). Por ejemplo:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((worksheet2!A:A=A3)*1)
```

You could put the above formula in cell B3, where A3 is the name you want to find in `worksheet2`.

Comment: Yes, this is a tested example. Note that this compares one string to another and counts the number of times the comparison evaluates to true.

Comment: @DavidZemens Apparently it does.  Can't get it to return anything but a number, though, so the end result is no different than just using a straight-up `COUNTIF`.

Comment: Except that there is less formula to debug when you next have to change the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

=COUNTIF() Is the function you are looking for

In a column adjacent to Worksheet1 column A:

```
=countif(worksheet2!B:B,worksheet1!A3)
```

This will search worksheet 2 ALL of column B for whatever you have in cell A3

See the MS Office reference for =COUNTIF(range,criteria) [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-function-HP010069840.aspx?CTT=3)!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine this all into one formula, but you need to use a regular `IF` first to find out if the `VLOOKUP` came back with something, then use your `COUNTIF` if it did.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!A1:A9,1,FALSE)),"Not there",COUNTIF(Sheet2!A1:A9,B1))
```

In this case, **Sheet2-A1:A9** is the range I was searching, and **Sheet1-B1** had the value I was looking for ("To retire" in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A3,worksheet2!A:A,0))),COUNTIF(worksheet2!A:A,A3),"No Match Found")`

Answer (score 0):

If your are referring to two worksheets please use this formula

```
=COUNTIF(Worksheet2!$A$1:$A$50,Worksheet1cellA1)
```

In case referring to to more than two worksheets please use this formula

```
=COUNTIF(Worksheet2!$A$1:$A$50,Worksheet1cellA1)+=COUNTIF
(Worksheet3!$A$1:$A$50,Worksheet1cellA1)+=
               COUNTIF(Worksheet4!$A$1:$A$50,Worksheet1cellA1)
```