# Count instances of value by specified row

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I'm having trouble creating a formula that will do the following:

Use two criteria from sheet 1 to count the number of times a value appears on sheet 2. Here is the tricky part - Criteria 1 provides the search key that identifies the row on sheet 2 that the search is to be conducted. For example, in the below data I am looking for a return in Sheet 1, cell c1, that counts how many times the number `12` appears in the row in sheet 2 that begins with `blue`. Similarly, in I am looking for a return in Sheet 1, cell c2, that counts how many times the number `4` appears in the row in sheet  that begins with `red`.

```
 - Sheet 1
-------a------b-------c------d
1------blue---12------2
2------red----4-------2

 - Sheet 2
------a-------b-------c------d
1-----blue----12------12-----4
2-----gray----10------5------12
3-----red-----12------4------4
```

To the best of my understanding, I'm looking for some kind of combination of a VLOOKUP and COUNT function. This forum was helpful: [Combining COUNT IF AND VLOOK UP EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575641/combining-count-if-and-vlook-up-excel) but I was ultimately not successful with the approach.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
 =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Sheet 2'!"&MATCH(A1,'Sheet 2'!A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(A1,'Sheet 2'!A:A,0)),B1)
```